# Is MySQL data returned from the query buffered?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If I run mysql_query() with SELECT statement, then while I am processing all the records another process amends some data from the result set, which was not yet processed. Using mysql_fetch_row() do I get old data or updated data?

For example:
Table:

```
id data
1  a
2  b
3  c
4  d
```

I have processed rows 1 and 2, then row with *id* 3 and changed *data* to **e**
Calling mysql_fetch_row() will get me an array with *data* equal to **c** or **e**?

Comment: You will get 'old' data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`mysql_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) the result will be buffered. If you want it unbuffered then you'd use [`mysql_unbuffered_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-unbuffered-query.php), though keep in mind the following:

> The benefits of **mysql_unbuffered_query()** come at a cost: you cannot
>   use [mysql_num_rows()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) and mysql_data_seek() on a result set returned
>   from **mysql_unbuffered_query()**, until all rows are fetched. You also
>   have to fetch all result rows from an unbuffered SQL query before you
>   can send a new SQL query to MySQL, using the same *link_identifier*.

Although, you shouldn't be using `mysql` functions anymore, anyway...

Comment: Thanks. I know I should not. I am slowly migrating to MySQLi, but large portion of projects are still on mysql.